# How can I add .lnk file to the SVN repository on the network volume?

Tags: svn, windows-8, tortoisesvn, access-denied

When I'm trying to add .lnk file to the SVN repository on the network volume on Windows 8 I get the following error:

```
Commit succeeded, but other errors follow:
Error bumping revisions post-commit (details follow):
Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with 'C:\Sources', work
 item 737 (file-commit Crashlytics.lnk)
Can't set file
 'C:\Sources\Crashlytics.framework\Crashlytics.lnk'
 read-write: Access denied.
```

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the following workaround:

1. Remove commited folder.
2. Checkout it again.

P.S. .lnk files on Crashlytics.framework are unnecessary.